# class-validator - Validate that an array of strings matches a value

Tags: javascript, validation, class-validator

I'm using the class-validator npm package and would like to validate that the type property of request body matches one either 'organization' or 'student'.

How would I do this with this package?

This doesn't work:

```
@IsIn(['organization', 'student'])
type: string
```

Request body example:

```
{
   "type": "organization",
   "email": "email@email.com",
   "password": "veryscretpwd"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this in your model class.

```
{
        "type": {
                type: String,
                enum: ['organization', 'student'],
                required: [true, 'Type is required.']
        },
        "email": ...
}
```

Instead of @IsIn use enum.

Comment: Made it work using that, also my initial solution worked as well but I made a typo. Thanks!